# Can the input dimension of denoising autoencoder be n*1？

Tags: python, reshape, autoencoder

I built a denoising autoencoder to disaggregate the total power. I have power data from 7 days(sample rate = 1min), and I split them in four-day for training(5760 data items) and three-day for testing(4320 data items). Can I reshape the input data of denoising autoencoder into (5760,1,1) for training model？

```
# Using 5min data  
x_train = x_train.reshape((1152,5,1))
y_train = y_train.reshape((1152,5,1))
y_test = y_test.reshape((864,5,1))
x_test = x_test.reshape((864,5,1))
# Using 1min data  
x_train = x_train.reshape((5760,1,1))
y_train = y_train.reshape((5760,1,1))
y_test = y_test.reshape((4320,1,1))
x_test = x_test.reshape((4320,1,1))
```

Comment: This might be achieved in different ways. Could you provide a piece of your code?Then it will be easier to help you.

Comment: Sure. I just confused that both reshaping input data in (5760,1,1) using 1min data and reshaping input data in (1152,5,1) using 5min data are acceptable input format for autoencoder.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.